# Регулярные выражения.Поиск повсторяющихся элементов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url

У меня есть к примеру

```
stackoverflow.com//
```

Мне нужна регулярка которая находит повторяющиеся друг за другом слеши.

Comment: такая что ли `\/{2,}`

Comment: А зачем их искать? Что вы этим хотите добиться, возможно есть вариант без регулярок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну собственно вот такая: `//+`.

https://ideone.com/KSERkr

```
echo preg_replace("#//+#", "((($0)))", "stackoverflow.com//");
```